# I am not able to update to Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio

"[image: screenshot]Plugin incompatible with the new build found: Firebase Services."

When I check for updates, it is showing me the above message.

Comment: are you not able to update by clicking "Update and Restart"?

Comment: I tried 3 times and it worked at last. But why is it showing me incompatible?

Comment: even I'am getting same error. So what shuld I do?

Comment: Just update it. There is no problem after update.